# How to create youtube overlays?

Tags: youtube

If you look at this video by FunForLouis:

You can see that there are three overlays that link to other content of his. I was wondering if anyone else has found how to do this themselves.

Comment: I was thinking, that it is "Cards" or "Annatations"... But was unable to reproduce that on my account

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Upon further research, this only seems to be available to high-tier YouTube Creator accounts. I haven't been able to find an example of this from an account with less than 1M subscribers. Here's the Creator tier levels:

https://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/en-GB/benefit-levels.html?noapp=1

ORIGINAL: This is a feature called "Cards" on YouTube. Your account must be in good standing to use this. Go to your video and hit "Edit" then navigate to the "Cards" menu. Here, you can add cards and select the content you want to display. Up to 5 can be added on one video at a time. Here's some documentation and a tutorial:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6140493?hl=en

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cards are different. They come up as squares that are on the side of the screen. I am looking for the way to add these round circular items.

Comment: Upon further research, this only seems to be available to high-tier YouTube Creator accounts. I haven't been able to find an example of this from an account with less than 1M subscribers. Let me know if you find information or examples that say otherwise.